# Using c# code in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I am trying to use `C# in javascript` like we are using it in `MVC Razor View` using `@ sign`,

like suppose an `array name list` is passed to the `View` so we can access it in `View` like:

**View**

```
     Length of array :  <input type="text"  value="@Model.list.Length" />

                  Or we can iterate list array also like:

         @for(int i=0; i< Model.list.Length; i++)
         {
             console.log(Model.list[i]);
         }
```

But my question is how we can iterate or use this array in the javascript code , something similar to :

**JS**

```
      for(var i=0; i<@Model.list.Length; i++)
      {
        $("body").append("<h1></h1>").html(@Model.list[i]);
      }
```

Thanks !

Comment: You (usually) can't run C# on the client side, where Javascript usually runs.

Comment: This is like riding a bike inside a car. Both are vehicles and there are separate roads for them. C# runs on the server. JS runs inside the browser.

Comment: To make this work, you need a preprocessor, who translates the `C#` commands into native js. This is pretty easy for plain values, and a lot trickier for complex objects. If your preprocessor is capable to convert a `C#`-Object into a `JS` object, then you can do this. If not, you can't because you won't be able to access the values of the array.

Comment: For templates you can do http://jsfiddle.net/kut9R/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i posted in my comment, this is a bit tricky. However, you can try to construct a javascript object with your c#.

Something like this (i don't know how this works exactly...):

```
var array = [
   @for(var i = 0; i < Model.list.Length-1; i++){  @Model.list[i] , }
   @Model.list[length]
]
```

which should result in:

```
var array = [
         val1,
         val2,
         val3,
         valn
]
```

Now you have an js var `array`, you can work with in your entire document.

Comment: It should be noted that if those values are strings, it will not auto-generate the quotes and so they'll be processed as variables instead of literal strings. Otherwise, nice, clean answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it exactly that way. What you can do is use the C# to generate the javascript code for each line like this:

```
//...javascript code...

@for(var i = 0; i < Model.list.Length; i++)
{
    $("body").append("<h1></h1>").html('@(Model.list[i])');
}

//...more javascript code...
```

This should output like this:

```
//...javascript code...

$("body").append("<h1></h1>").html(listitem0);
$("body").append("<h1></h1>").html(listitem1);
$("body").append("<h1></h1>").html(listitem2);
//etc.

//...more javascript code...
```

Comment: i guess it's cleaner to construct the js-array and loop over it.

Comment: I would also put line inside _for_ loop inside `<text>` tag.